# Best framework for a subscription-based web service business/site?

Tags: web-services, frameworks, subscription

We're developing a new web service that will be free for low-volume users and  subscription-based for higher volume users. Most users will probably invoke it via a plugin for their cms or blog system, and some will use api toolkits for various programming languages. The web service, itself, is straightforward to expose to users, but a full-featured web application needed to configure and manage access to it using a subscription-based business model is more complicated.

We need to build, buy or find a solution that powers a self-service website which lets people:

- sign up for free or paid accounts
- select and configure service options
- enter payment credentials
- edit their account and billing profiles
- review their service usage and billing history
- suspend or cancel their accounts

From an admin perspective, we would also like the system to let us:

- monitor and manage service status
- log user activity and service consumption
- review and manage user accounts
- manage recurring billing, flag problem accounts
- manage message templates for communicating with users
- configure service packages, options and discount codes
- perform other, similar administrative activities

This seems like standard stuff that any web-based, self-service subscription system might need. I'm wondering whether anyone out there knows of a package that provides most or all of these features? We're open to considering various programming languages and platforms, although it will be most convenient to deploy and run this on a linux system.

If there's not a solid, open-source solution out there, then we might be interested in sponsoring the creation of one. I'm looking forward to hearing insights form the community. Thanks!

Rick

Answer (score 1):

Subscription management and billing operations are a pain to implement yourself.  I would suggest checking out [Zuora](http://www.zuora.com/).  Even though there's some cost there, they have a nice API for their cloud service.

Not sure if that would fit with the model you have in mind, but they do take away a headache.

Answer (score 1):

Go with FastSpring , www.fastspring.com

It rocks it addresses all things you mentioned + more.

http://www.fastspring.com/features-subscription.php

Answer (score 0):

METRO sounds like a suitable choice to me considering your preferred server OS:

https://metro.dev.java.net/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, REA_ANDREW. Looking at the Metro page I don't see any indication that it supports user and subscription management or recurring billing.

Powering the web service is easy, but operating it as a business is more complicated. We're seeking a framework to power that part!

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia has a great comparison table for web service frameworks. This may be a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_frameworks