# Open Source Platform for Subscription-based Web service?

Tags: web-services, open-source, lamp, subscription

Looking for a LAMP-based platform for subscription-based Web service that I can easily hack to fit my needs, which one would you recommend based on the following criteria:

1. Documentation
2. Install base
3. Support community
4. Scalability
5. Availability of plugins/add-ons
6. Correctness of Design (i.e. no need
   to hack core files to add a plugin)

Feel free to add other criteria.

Comment: In the meanwhile I managed to find these two related threads [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619062/best-framework-for-a-subscription-based-web-service-business-site) & [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374260/what-ecommerce-platform-would-you-use-to-manage-traditional-products-subscripti) but they don't really address the issues I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has a great comparison table of web service frameworks. This could be a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_frameworks

Comment: +1 for attempting to answer but "web service frameworks" are way too general... they are more like a programming language rather than a package accepting a much smaller set of customizations.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to go with a CMS and use a subscription plugin.

Joomla: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions

Wordpress: https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership/